# How to compile nested css rules using javascript

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, stylesheet

I need a little help with making my own css-compiler in JavaScript.

**How can I make a compiler that compiles this nested rules example:**

```
html{
    background: #2E2E2E;
    body{
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        a{
            color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
            &:hover{
                color: rgb(200, 0, 255);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Into this:**

```
html{
    background: #2E2E2E;
}
html body{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
html body a{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
html body a:hover{
    color: rgb(200, 0, 255);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

If you vote down, please tell me why.

Comment: Are you using a compiler? maybe look at http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: I am not using a compiler, I am making a compiler.

Comment: What have you done so far.

Comment: How are you 'making' it? You would simply write rules to reformat the stylesheet... All Sass Less or Scss are is a differently formatted text file and the pre-compilers just read the format and output the intended css.
If you are writing the compiler you must write the rules.. Read a file, identify the rules and patterns return output. Simple yet very long process.

I don't know why you would reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I have tried some things with RegExp… None have been successful though. That is why I asked here.

Comment: @DanielTate I want to write a javascript code that can compile something in the syntax of the top, into the below example.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by mentioning that building your own css-compiler is no joke. It is a serious thing. You should use something like Sass, Less, or Stylus. If they are missing a feature you need, you should build a plugin for them, rather than try to implement your own engine.

Having said that, an answer to your question may be [reworkcss](https://github.com/reworkcss/rework). It is a project that people will use to make their own CSS-compiler.

Comment: I don't want anything t involves node js.

Comment: What language do you want your CSS-compiler to be in?

Comment: So, you want it to compile in the browser?

Comment: Yeah… I know there are a few downsides, but I want to try this.